# Scope of middleware functions in express.js

Tags: node.js, express, scope, middleware, node.js-connect

I'm learning express.js / node.js and have a good but not excellent understanding of the javascript prototype model. Hence, I'm a bit confused on the way middleware can be stacked in express.js's routing mechanisms.

Say we have this [code](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#route-middleware)

```
function andRestrictTo(role) {
    return function(req, res, next) {
       req.authenticatedUser.role == role
           ? next() : next(new Error('Unauthorized'));
   }
}

app.del('/user/:id', loadUser, andRestrictTo('admin'), function(req, res){
    res.send('Deleted user ' + req.user.name);
});
```

Since andRestrictTo(role) returns a middleware, it get's executed in the routing chain - I got that. However:

1. Where does the req, res, next parameters come from in the returned function? I guess that the "chain" is somehow queuing it and assings the parameters, but this is a bit too vague for a deeper understanding ...
2. What is happening with the Error that is raised as next's parameter? Does an error simply break the middleware chain?
3. If I would want to package the restriction mechanism to a separate file / module (like a security framework), how would that be done?

It would be cool if someone could point out the basic idea :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1) `req` and `res` come from the very source of Express JS, i.e. Node.JS `http.createServer` handler (both variables are modified a bit before actually hitting Express' handler). At that point Express holds the array of all routes and applies `req`, `res` and `next` function to each route. `next` function knows at which middleware we are at the moment (due to some scoping tricks) and calling it like this: `next()` takes you to the next handler.

2) When the error is raised (actually not *raised*, but passed to), the `next` function takes you to the error handler, which you can define using `error` method of `app`, for example (taken from [Express documentation](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#error-handling)):

```
app.error(function(err, req, res, next){
    if (err instanceof NotFound) {
        res.render('404.jade');
    } else {
        next(err);
    }
});
```

Raising `error` breakes a chain of middlewares and takes you to the chain of error handlers (as you can see, you use `next` in error handlers as well).

3) Not difficult at all:

**security.js**

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('Security middleware!');
    next();
}
```

**app.js**

```
app.get('/', require('./security'), ...);
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Express's (actually Connect's) routing code takes an HTTP request and begins passing it along to all the middleware functions, calling each of them with the `req` and `res` that came along with the request, and adding a `next` that invokes the part of the routing code that passes control along to the next middleware function in the chain.

2) No error has been raised (only a `throw` statement can actually raise an error). The routing code recognizes that a middleware function has returned an `Error` object, and deals with that appropriately.

3) You'd just put it into a module that exports `andRestrict` (if it were the only externally-usable function in the module, you'd set `exports=andRestrict` and then invoke it with `require('mymodule')`); otherwise you'd set `exports.andRestrict=<body of your function>` and invoke it in two steps: `mymodule=require('mymodule')` early on, and `mymodule.andRestrict` later on (e.g. when passing it as middleware)).